# Finding value for ABC

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int abc;
    int total = 1000;
    for (abc = 220000000; abc < 240000000; abc++) {
      String string1 = Integer.toString(abc);
      int a, b, c;
      a = 0;
      b = 0;
      c = 0;
      int a2 = squared(a);
      int b2 = squared(b);
      int c2 = squared(c);
      a = Integer.parseInt(string1.substring(0, 3));
      b = Integer.parseInt(string1.substring(3, 6));
      c = Integer.parseInt(string1.substring(6, 9));
      if (a < b && a < c && b < c && a2 < b2 && b2 < c2 && a + b + c == total) {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + abc);
      } else {
        System.exit(0); // testing
      }
    }
  }

  public static int squared(int x) {
    return (x * x);
  }
}
```

This is my code. I am trying to have the program print the value of abc so that a is less than b which is less than c. And where a squared is less than b squared which is less than c squared. Also, a+b+c must equal 1000. I tried making abc one whole value and using substrings to differ between a, b, and c. An example would be like 224,356,446. An with the substrings it would make a=224, b=356, and c=446. When I run the program, nothing is being printed. The else statement is being invoked because the system exits. Can anyone help?

Comment: If `a < b < c` then for any positive values `a^2 < b^2 < c^2` is always true. Also: if `a<b` and `b<c` then `a<c`, so you only need 3 checks here: `if( a<b && b<c && a+b+c == total)`.

Comment: Why do you assign `a2, b2, c2` before you've given `a, b, c` non-zero values?

Comment: As for the if-statement: think about what happens if you're not at the end and didn't find an answer yet: do you really want to exit right away? I doubt so, thus continue the loop until you've found an answer - in which case you can use a `break;` to exit the loop. With this, no `System.exit()` would be needed at all.

Comment: You're calling `squared()` to get the squared value BEFORE you've figured out what the actual values, a, b and c are.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to keep building strings: `c = abc % 1000; b = (abc / 1000) % 1000; a = (abc / 1000000) % 1000;`. But you're going to go through a lot of iterations before `a < b < c`. And there's no real point in iterating for `c`, just assign `c = total - (a + b);`, and do correspondingly fewer iterations.

Comment: Another thing: you don't need 20,000,000 iterations but could loop from 220 to 240 for `a` and from 1 to 1000-a-1 for `b`. `c` would then be `1000 - a - b`.

Answer (score 0):

You print nothing because you do not have a match on your first iteration.  The lack of a match fires `System.exit(0)` so the program exits without another iteration.

You have appeared to make the assumption that that `a`, `b`, `c` are non-negative integers so I'll adopt that same assumption.  As such, if `a < b < c` then `a^2 < b^2 < c^2` so we do not have to test for the latter condition.

If `a + b + c == 1000` and `a < b < c` then if `a==0` and `b==1` (their minimum values) then `c == 999`.  So we know we do not have to iterate beyond 999 in any case.  This bound could be further optimized a bit but doing so is pointless since he output operation far outweighs the iteration cost.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int a = 0 ; a < 999 ; ++a) {
    for (int b = a+1 ; b < 999 ; ++b) { // a < b
      int c = 1000 - a - b;
      if (c <= b) {
        break;
      }
      System.out.printf("%d  %d, %d, %d", ++count, a, b, c).println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the innermost loop: just set `int c = 1000 - a - b;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  you are correct - I will repair